# Ordenamiento Burbuja a números aleatorios

Tags: java

Estoy queriendo hacer un vector de tamaño aleatorio entre 1 y 15, y a este vector cargarlo con número aleatorios hasta el 100 y a estos ordenarlos con el método burbuja de menor a mayor, avance con algo pero no logro terminarlo, habrá ayuda para un estudiante desesperado?

```
    import java.util.*;
    public class Principal
    {
        public static void NumAleatorio()
       {
           Random r = new Random();
          
            for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++)
           {
               int a =(r.nextInt(14)+ 1);
               int[] vector = new int[a];
                    
                for (int i = 0; i < vector.length; i++)
               { 
                   vector[i] = r.nextInt(100);
                   System.out.println(vector[i]);
               }
           }           
       }
    public static int[] Burbuja(int[] v)
   {
        for(int j = 0; j < v.length; j++)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i  < v.length - 1; i++)
            {
                 if(v[i] > v[i+1])
                 {
                     int aux= v[i];
                     v[i] = v[i+1];
                     v[i+1] = aux;
                 }
            }
        }
        return v;
   }
}
```

Comment: Amigo desesperado: cuál es la falla actual? Que te está saliendo actualmente en el código (o qué error muestra)? (Me sentí como en sección de preguntas de revista de adolescentes :P )

Comment: Jaja, y mirá al tamaño del vector tiene que tiene que ser aleatorio lo tengo, la cantidad de números aleatorios del tamaño del vector lo tengo, lo único que me falta es relacionarlo con el método de burbuja, el cual lo tengo allí escrito pero no estaría pudiendo relacionarlo como para que me ordene el vector de [i] posiciones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agrego código completo.

Al método `NumAleatorio()` le hice algunos cambios y ahora retorna el vector creado y lleno.

El método `Burbuja()` no necesita retornar el arreglo ya que lo modifica por referencia.

```
import java.util.*;
    
    public class Test {
    
        public static void main(String... args) {
    
            int[] vector = NumAleatorio();
    
            // ordenar el vector
            Burbuja(vector);
            // imprimir el vector
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(vector));
    
        }
    
        public static int[] NumAleatorio() {
            Random r = new Random();
            // crear vector de tamaño aleatorio entre 1 y 15
            int[] vector = new int[r.nextInt(15) + 1];
    
            // recorrer el vector
            // la propiedad length nos da la longitud
            for (int i = 0; i < vector.length; i++) {
                // asignar un valor aleatorio entre 1 y 100
                vector[i] = r.nextInt(100) + 1;
            }
    
            return vector;
    
        }
    
        public static void Burbuja(int[] v) {
    
            for (int j = 0; j < v.length; j++) {
                for (int i = 0; i < v.length - 1; i++) {
                    if (v[i] > v[i + 1]) {
                        int aux = v[i];
                        v[i] = v[i + 1];
                        v[i + 1] = aux;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Gracias genio! Mil gracias!! Que buena comunidad..

Answer (score 0):

Puedes generar un numero random para asignar las posiciones del array sin un ciclo `for`

`int random = r.nextInt(15) + 1;`

`int arrayRandom [] = new int [random];`

Después recorre las posiciones del array para asignarles el numero random del 1 al 100:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayRandom.length; i++) {
        arrayRandom[i] = r.nextInt(100) + 1; 
        System.out.println(arrayRandom[i]);
}
```

Por ultimo creas un método para ordenar dicho array

```
private static int[] ordenarArray(int[] arrayRandom) {
     for (int j = 0; j < arrayRandom.length; j++) {
         for (int i = 0; i < arrayRandom.length - 1; i++) {
             if (arrayRandom[i] > arrayRandom[i + 1]) {
                 int aux = arrayRandom[i];
                 arrayRandom[i] = arrayRandom[i + 1];
                 arrayRandom[i + 1] = aux;
             }
         }
     }
     return arrayRandom;
}
```

Te dejo el ejemplo completo que he realizado con comentarios:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class ArrayRandom {
    public static void main(String []args) {
    
        Random r = new Random();
        int random = r.nextInt(15) + 1; // Guardamos un numero aleatorio de 1 al 15
        System.out.print("El array contara con: " + random + " posiciones.\n");
        int arrayRandom [] = new int [random];  //Asiganamo tamaño al array con dicho numero aleatoriao         
    
        System.out.println("\nLos valores del array son: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayRandom.length; i++) {
            arrayRandom[i] = r.nextInt(100) + 1; //Asignamos a cada posición del array un numero aleatorio del 1 al 100
            System.out.println(arrayRandom[i]);
        }
    
        int[] arrayOrdenado = ordenarArray(arrayRandom); //Llamamos al método para ordenar el array y guardarlo ordenado 
    
        //Visualizamos el array ordenado de menor a mayor
        System.out.println("\nLos valores del array ordenados son:");          
        for(int i = 0; i < arrayOrdenado.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(arrayOrdenado[i]);
        }
    }

    //Método para ordenar el array de menor a mayor
    private static int[] ordenarArray(int[] arrayRandom) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arrayRandom.length; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayRandom.length - 1; i++) {
                if (arrayRandom[i] > arrayRandom[i + 1]) {
                    int aux = arrayRandom[i];
                    arrayRandom[i] = arrayRandom[i + 1];
                    arrayRandom[i + 1] = aux;
                }
            }
        }
        return arrayRandom;
   }
}
```

Comment: Gracias viejo!! Mil gracias!! Se agradece..